# how to exit from a pyplot loop?

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I have a python program using pyplot (backend:tkagg), in which simply a matplotlib is created with some stuff in it.
When I want to exit the program, I immediately call:

```
plt.close('all')
```

to shut it down.
Strangely enough, the program dosnt exit.

Following it with the debugger I saw that after everithing is done, it returns to

```
class Show(ShowBase):
    def mainloop(self):
        Tk.mainloop()
```

in **backend_tkagg.py**,

followed by

```
if not is_interactive():
            self.mainloop()
```

in the same file, then to

```
def show(*args, **kw):
    global _show
    _show(*args, **kw)
```

in **pyplot.py**
So it appears that I am still in the pyplot loop!

How do I exit from it correctly?

thanks...

Comment: Do you think you could give an example of a short code-snippet which can demonstrate this behaviour? Although your debugging looks interesting, it's hard to test ourselves without an [example](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Are you using any IDE, or just the console? Some IDE's doing interesting things behind the curtain to manage the GUI Loop which might be giving you trouble.

Comment: 1) do you have `plt.ion()`? 2) are you not using a version of matplotlib older than `1.0`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not in the `pyplot` loop per-say, but the main loop associated with the GUI toolkit (this is the loop that deals with all the user interactions with the GUI).  I suspect it is safe to just call `exit()` in your program and let object clean up deal with properly tearing down the `TK` objects/mainloop

maybe related :
[Exit Tks mainloop in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2732847/exit-tks-mainloop-in-python),